# Bug developing Pong Game

Tags: c++, sfml

I am creating my first game, Pong, and I have a little bug that I don't know how to fix. If the ball hits the pad from the above, it enters inside it and exit on the other side.

Here is a link with the video to understand the bug better [Pong Game Bug](https://ufile.io/9af2g).

I'll also post my code here so you can see how I tried to do it.

```
    // Ball

    ball.move(xVelocityBall, yVelocityBall);

    // Colosion for pad1
    if (ball.getGlobalBounds().intersects(pad1.getGlobalBounds()) == true)
    {
        xVelocityBall = -xVelocityBall;
        hit.play();
    }

    // Colosion for pad2
    if (ball.getGlobalBounds().intersects(pad2.getGlobalBounds()) == true)
    {
        xVelocityBall = -xVelocityBall;
        hit.play();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We'd love to help you debug, but your question doesn't provide enough detail (for example, we do not know what type `ball` is). If you can edit your question to provide a [mcve], you will be more likely to get meaningful help. (Also, debuggers and print statements are your friends! Verify that the bounds of the different elements in your game are what you expect. Step through each part and make sure the comparisons are being done correctly.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when your ball intersects with the pad, you change the sign of the x component of your velocity vector but your ball is still on the pad so next frame the velocity's sign is changed again resulting in the ball staying stuck on the pad.

This kind of collisions need some attention because you will encounter alot of edge cases.